# js: how to stop a loop after 1 second?

Tags: javascript

I try to write a function that shakes/nudges a window popup

```
this.nudge = function() {
    var stopped = false;
    var x=10;
    setTimeout(function() {
        stopped = true;
    },1000);

    for (i=0;;i++){
        if (stopped) break;
        window.moveBy(0,x)
        window.moveBy(x,0)
        window.moveBy(0,-x)
        window.moveBy(-x,0)
   }
}
```

Problem is : it never stops !

Comment: Of course - you never give it a chance to execute the `stopped = true`. Javascript (or to be more precise, the way `setTimeout` works in a browser) isn't multi-threaded. You're blocking the main thread with your cycle. This simply isn't how you're supposed to code effects in JS.

Comment: You could use an interval instead and 'shake' the popup inside that interval. This way you can stop shaking the moment you remove the interval. Alternatively don't use a loop, move the 'shaking' code into its own function and have that function call itsself until stopped = true.

Answer (score 11):

Since JavaScript is single-threaded (as @Luaan mentioned in the comments), your infinite loop will run infinitely and prevent any timeouts or other events from being executed. The runtime won't even try to preempt your loop (break it in the middle to run other code) and will wait until your main function has returned -- which never happens.

You cannot use a busy wait or other, similar loops in JS: they prevent the browser's UI from responding and will cause any events to be deferred until execution has finished and the script thread is free.

To process your loop correctly in an event-friendly fashion, you can either set it up as a timeout every repetition or an interval, like:

```
this.nudge = function() {
    var x = 10;
    var loop = setInterval(function() {
      window.moveBy(0,x)
      window.moveBy(x,0)
      window.moveBy(0,-x)
      window.moveBy(-x,0)
    }, 100);

    setTimeout(function() {
      clearInterval(loop);
    }, 1000);
}
```

This simplifies your code by removing the `stopped` variable and simply started/clearing a deferred loop when the timeout has expired. You can adjust the timing on either function to change the rate of animation and overall duration.

Comment: 100ms is a fine value to interval over. I'd suggest though 16ms as this is 60fps.

Comment: If you want to tie the animation to the framerate, `requestAnimationFrame` is probably the best option, although a 16ms (or 32ms) interval should work well.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about such solution?

```js
var i = 0;
(function a(timeout, startTime) {
  console.log(i++);
  if (Date.now() - startTime > timeout) return;
  setTimeout(function() {
    /* window.moveBy(0, x);
    window.moveBy(x, 0);
    window.moveBy(0, -x);
    window.moveBy(-x, 0); */
    a(timeout, startTime);
  }, 0);
})(1000, Date.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something lie this :

```
this.nudge = function() {
    var x=10;
    var ts = Date.now();
    while(Date.now()-ts<1000){
        window.moveBy(0,x)
        window.moveBy(x,0)
        window.moveBy(0,-x)
        window.moveBy(-x,0)
   }
}
```